# jQuery: add and remove elements as the window is resized but always cover the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, append

I want to create a baseline grid for my website that shows always baselines to the bottom of the page.

What I do is I create one initial baseline that is styled through css.

```
<figure id="lines">
    <div class='base-line bl1'></div>
</figure>
```

and then create new ones till I reach the bottom of the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var diff = Math.floor( $('body').height() / $('.base-line').height() );
            for ( var i = 1; i <= diff; i++ )
                $('#lines').append("<div class='base-line bl" + i + "'></div>");
        });
    </script>
```

However when I resize the page (e.g. decrease the height) there are baselines left over. And when I increase the height of the document dynamically (e.g. change some values with a media-query) the baselines don't reach the bottom of the page.

Is it possible to right a resize-handler that adds and removes the baselines when resizing? I guess it's rather unperformant if I delete all `base-line`s on each resize and draw all of them for each resize-state.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the function that creates the base lines

```
function addBaseLines(){
    $('#lines').clear();
    var diff = Math.floor( $('body').height() / $('.base-line').height() );
    for ( var i = 1; i <= diff; i++ ){
       append("<div class='base-line bl" + i + "'></div>");
    }
}
```

You could do this

```
var timeout = null;

$(window).resize(function(){
    if (timeout!=null){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout( addBaseLines, 1000); // only do when the user is "done" 

});
```

See in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrJtX/20/)

Performance is not terrible if you use the timeout...

To improve performance, just removes the ones out of sight, but I think it's not that critical

Answer (score 0):

well you could,

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var height = $(window).height();  /*or width*/
   var min = 500; //for example
   if(height < min){
      $('.base-line').hide();
   }else{
      $('.base-line').show();
   }
});
```

But i am not sure if you want to hide/show or remove/add (**I** would do first)